# How to increase layout via touching up and down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

In my project we have 2 Linearlayout inside layout file, we want increase/decrease height via touch up and down

[image]

Inside a layout I have a horizontal view for changing height of layout. This view is the second layout

Answer (score 1):

1. First Detect amount of area scrolled by view using [Android listView
   find the amount of pixels scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471075/android-listview-find-the-amount-of-pixels-scrolled)
2. Then set this scrolled height dynamically to the view [Android set
   height and width of Custom view programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042197/android-set-height-and-width-of-custom-view-programmatically)

Comment: i think it's not useful for my solution, because i have a view in center of screen

Comment: i added PixelScrollDetector class and now how to use second link that you were wrote?

Comment: are you getting scrolled  height?

Comment: @ Akshay Tilekar  how to get  scrolled height in view ?

Comment: @sr_farzad find view by id and set height to it as mentioned in above links

Comment: yes i could set  height,and now can i change height via touch ?

Comment: change it according to onScrollStateChanged

Comment: can you write a sample using onScrollStateChanged in LinearLayout ?

Comment: but my problem is about touch for change position inside layout

Comment: what are you achieved ? have you got scrolled pixels?

Comment: @ Akshay Tilekar  i could move layout inside screen and it soloved and new problem is when user drag it view going out of screen.how to limit it ? my width of view is Match_Parent

Ask Question

Comment: Try the adjustViewBounds attribute:

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: is adjustViewBounds using for ImageView or RelativeLayout?

Comment: read this :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the problem.complete code is :

```
public class MultiTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {


    private float mPrevX;
    private float mPrevY;

    public QuranActivity mainActivity;
    public MultiTouchListener(QuranActivity mainActivity1) {
        mainActivity = mainActivity1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float currX,currY;
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                mPrevX = event.getX();
                mPrevY = event.getY();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {

                int w = mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
                int h = mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;



                currX = event.getRawX();
                currY = event.getRawY();


               ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());


                //marginParams.topMargin = (int)(currY - mPrevY);


            /*    if(currX>w){
                    marginParams.leftMargin = (int)(currX - mPrevX)-100;
                }
                else {
                    marginParams.leftMargin = (int)(currX - mPrevX);
                }


                if(currY>h){
                    marginParams.rightMargin = (int)(currY - mPrevY)-100;
                }
                else {
                    marginParams.rightMargin = (int)(currY - mPrevY);
                }
*/




                marginParams.setMargins(0, (int)(currY - mPrevY),0, 0);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                Log.e("onTouch X",currX - mPrevX+"  " + "" );
                Log.e("onTouch Y",currY - mPrevY+"  " + "" );



                break;
            }



            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```